# Exercise of Rick Miranda is wrong? Actions over Riemann sphere

Tags: group-actions, riemann-surfaces, riemann-sphere

I'm studying the book Rick Miranda, Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces and I have a question about the exercise H of page 84.

[image]

The book says that $z \mapsto exp(2\pi i /r)z$ is an automorphism of the Riemann Sphere $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ but it's not. It's not even injective. I don't know how to interpret this. I know that I can prove that the group generated by this two elements it's a dihedral group. But I'm interested in this example because I need actions over riemann surfaces (specially from dihedral groups).

EDIT: Let $ e^{2\pi i /r} = \zeta$.  I misread because the map was $ z \mapsto \zeta \cdot z$ (Thanks Daniel Fischer).

**The real question:**

I want to prove that there are three branch points to the quotient map, with ramification numbers $2,2,r$. This is the same as proving that there exist $3$ orbits of size $r,r,2$.

I found one orbit of size $r$. It's the set of $r$-roots of unity.

I don't know how to find the other two orbits.

Comment: Why do you say the action is not injective?

Comment: Because $exp(2\pi i /r)z_1 = exp(2\pi i /r)z_2 $ iff $z_1- z_2 \in r \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: You misread, it's $$z \mapsto \bigl(e^{2\pi i/r}\bigr)\cdot z.$$

Comment: :O Thanks! That's all

Comment: It's a pity that a modern book has such a cumbersome typing standard as to make things confusing.

Comment: [Related later question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4184558/a-holomorphic-action-of-a-dihedral-group-on-the-riemann-sphere)