# A holomorphic action of a dihedral group on the Riemann sphere

Tags: group-actions, riemann-surfaces

> Show that the group of automorphisms of $\Bbb C_\infty$ generated by the two automorphisms sending $z$ to $\exp(2\pi i/r)z$ and sending $z$ to $1/z$ is a dihedral group of order $2r$, which acts holomorphically and effectively on $\Bbb C_\infty$. Show that there are three branch points to the quotient map.

This is an exercise in Miranda's book *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*, Chapter III.3. Here is my attempt: Let $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/r)$, $a(z)=\zeta z$, and $b(z)=1/z$. Then $a^r=1, b^2=1$, and $ba=a^{-1}b$, so the subgroup of $\text{Aut}(\Bbb C_\infty)$ generated by $a$ and $b$ is the dihedral group of order $2r$. Next, to show that there are three branch points, we have to show that there are three orbits of order $<2r$.

The orbit of $0$ consists of $\{0,\infty\}$, the orbit of $1$ consists of $\{1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\dots,\zeta^{r-1}\}$, and the orbit of $-1$ consists of $\{-1,-\zeta,-\zeta^2,\dots,-\zeta^{r-1}\}$. These three orbits are distinct if $r$ is odd, so in this case we are done. But if $r$ is even, then the oribts of $1$ and $-1$ are the same. Then what are the three orbits of order $<2r$ in the even $r$ case?

Edit: I've found that this question is related to this one: [Exercise of Rick Miranda is wrong? Actions over Riemann sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693617/exercise-of-rick-miranda-is-wrong-actions-over-riemann-sphere), but this one doesn't have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the three orbits of size $<2r$ are

- $\{0,\infty\}$
- the $r$th roots of unity
- the midpoints between the $r$th roots of unity on the unit circle, i.e. the $2r$th roots of unity which are not themselves $r$th roots of unity.

Any point $w$ not on the unit circle or the antipodal points $\{0,\infty\}$ has an orbit of size $2r$, consisting of the values $\zeta^k w^{\pm1}$. Geometrically, thinking about the dihedral action on the unit circle, the orbit of any point which is a shortest arc of length $\theta$ from an $r$th root of unity is the set of all points which are $\theta$ away, both clockwise and counterclockwise, from a root of unity. This will have size $2r$, *unless* these two sets of points coincide, so the clockwise and counterclockwise translates of the roots of unity "meet in the middle," which happens precisely at midpoints between roots of unity.